# hijri date format to mysql (invalid range)

Tags: mysql, date

here is the table structure:

```
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| date  | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

there query to insert date in this table:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp SET id = 3, date = '1392-01-01';
```

query run succeeds:

here if i run the query of:

```
   INSERT INTO tbl_temp SET id = 3, date = '1392-02-31';
```

result shows the value is **out of range**, so how i can set the column to get any value of date format, here i can set the column to text or varchar so it only get the data, but later i need to set some trigger regarding the date which i need the column type to be date>

NOTE: The problem is , date column has type of date (so in Gregorian) it will take any date from (0001-01-01) to (any) but it must be according to date fromat. as in application using hijri i need to insert the hijri date which (1393-02-31) but this is the date which is not in range of Gregorian date) so it will not allow the data to get to the database.

any solution to insert any date to mysql column of table
.
regards

Comment: datetime does not use the hijri calendar. you have to convert it.

Comment: i am inserting it manually to database, for example the date column is having type of date or datetime, but when i insert the value of date (1393-02-31) it shows of range here how i can make the date column to allow insert of any date from any time, for exampel from (0001-01-01) to (yyyy-mm-dd), is it posible????

Comment: Insert the Julian date instead. Or store a string (CHAR/VARCHAR) instead.

Comment: The range is fine. The problem is that it's treating it like Gregorian, and February doesn't have 31 days (xxxx-02-31). Convert date in app before inserting.

Comment: "A calendar applied to dates when it was not actually in use is called proleptic. Thus, if we assume there was never a cutover and Gregorian rules always rule, we have a proleptic Gregorian calendar. This is what is used by MySQL, as is required by standard SQL." So no standards compliant rdbms should support even Julian, let alone Ethiopian, Hebrew, or Hijri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that MySQL server does not supporting the hijri date so there are only two options:

1. application level customization: column date type,  will have to be varchar, or any text and we do the hijri input from the application just like input text and store as a text to database,
2. database level customization: we have to keep the database in Gregorian date type and manage the date changing in application view.

as far of the date(the column type was datetime, so the date which **1392-02-31** is not in the range of Gregorian date so it will reject it and keep it as a null.